# Blue flickering stripes on my MBP with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, graphics, macos-catalina

On my new Macbook Pro 16 late 2019, with Catalina 10.15.4 I recently found a weird problem with chrome (other browsers seems to work fine)

Some websites (maybe 1 in 100) appear broken with blue stripes flickering. Has anybody experienced a similar problem? Even here in Stack overflow the area around my profile avatar looks blueish. Specially the Chrome inspector is fully broken.

Restarting the computer always helps but the problem keeps coming back.

Is it a hardware problem? Do I need to get back to Apple?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I too have this issue

Comment: Why is this question closed? If it's not suited for this site, then for which other is it? There are 62k questions with a google-chrome tag on this site and this is a google chrome question, so I think it's appropriate.

Comment: This actually applies to all chromium-based apps, like Microsoft Teams

Comment: I've seen this in several applications, especially in MS Teams, however it's not just chromium. Certain content will also show the glitching even on Safari, for example https://pixijs.io/examples/#/graphics/advanced.js . The issue may also resolve itself by disconnecting external displays, then plugging them back in.

Answer (score 14):

I have the same issue on my MBP 16, with Catalina 10.15.4, and Chrome 80.0.3987.163. Like you said, a fresh restart will fix the issue.

It all starts again after resuming from suspend, but not always. I did not yet find a pattern.

I found disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome removes the symptoms.

Comment: chrome://settings/?search=hardware+acceleration

Comment: disable hardware acceleration worked. I only see these stripes on google spreadsheets pages ...

Comment: I have found out you can avoid full mac restart - sleep the mac, wait for mac to actually sleep (around 1 minute, fans go off). Then wake it up and restart only the problematic Chrome / chromium based app.

Comment: Disabling chrome hardware acceleration worked for me.

Comment: Disabling the hardware acceleration might fix it but this is a terrible solution for all but simple text browsing. It's used for a reason, good luck with videos with that disabled.